# Copy range of formulas across worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of formulas which need to be copied across all worksheets. The range goes from AB1:AC5. The formulas need to work across the worksheets and are taken from a worksheet called "Template" which is the first sheet in the workbook. I believe I have already selected the range and it will continue to only copy from "Template". How would I get it to paste onto every other sheet?

```
Sub FillSheets()
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range

 Dim worksheetsToSkip As Variant

 worksheetsToSkip = Array("Aggregated", "Collated Results", "Template", "End")
 Set rng = Sheet1.Range("AB1:AC5")

 For Each ws In Worksheets
    If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, worksheetsToSkip, 0)) Then


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you were quite near, since you had to use `Formula` property of `Range` object and a reference to the "source" range `Address`

also, you had a variable name mismatch: declared `sh As Worksheet` but then you used `ws`

try this:

```
Sub FillSheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Dim worksheetsToSkip As Variant

    worksheetsToSkip = Array("Aggregated", "Collated Results", "Template", "End")
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("AB1:AC5")

    For Each sh In Worksheets
       If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, worksheetsToSkip, 0)) Then sh.Range(rng.Address).Formula = rng.Formula
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies I think I worded this wrong. I have a formula on Template which need to be copied from there and pasted into the other sheets

Comment: well that's precisely what my code is doing  provided that 1) the "Template" sheet is `Sheet1` 2) formulas to be copied from "Template" sheet are in "AB1:AC5" 3) formulas are to be pasted in range "AB1:AC5" of any other sheet but those listed in `worksheetsToSkip`

Comment: for example I want to multiple whatever is in K3 with K4 in each worksheet and display it in AB1 of each worksheet respectively. When using this code I get =Template!A2 displayed in AB1

Answer (score 0):

## The Exclamation Mark Issue

### Cells Containing Sheet References

There is a worksheet named `Template`. You can write into cell `A1` the formula `=A2+A3`. You can also write `=Template!A2+A3` or `=Template!A2+Template!A3`. In all three cases the result is the same. But when you `Paste Special` the formulas into another sheet, you'll get different formulas in each case and therefore possibly different results. This code removes this possibility by pasting only the first scenario (`=A2+A3`).

### When does Excel write these sheet references to a sheet?

In our example the case `=Template!A2+A3` could have happened when the `Template` tab was selected, in the formula bar the equal sign (`=`) was entered, a different tab was clicked, then the `Template` tab was clicked, `A2+A3` was entered and `ENTER` was pressed.
The case `=Template!A2+Template!A3` could have happened when the `Template` tab was selected, in the formula bar the equal sign (`=`) was entered, a different tab was clicked, then the `Template` tab was clicked, `A2` was selected, again a different tab was clicked, (`+`) was entered, again the `Template` tab was clicked, `A3` was selected and `ENTER` was pressed.

```
Option Explicit

'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:  Pastes formulas from a range in an initial worksheet               *
'           to the same range in all worksheets that are not included          *
'           in a specified worksheet-names list of exceptions.                 *
' Remarks:  There has to be a worksheet with the codename "Sheet1"             *
'           in the workbook in which this code resides or it will not compile. *
'*******************************************************************************
Sub FillSheetsWithRangeOfFormulas()

  Const cStrRange = "AB1:AC5"                         ' Initial Range Address
  Const cStrSkip = "Aggregated,Collated Results,End"  ' List of Exceptions
  Const cStrSkipSeparator = ","                       ' List of Exceptions Sep.

  Dim objWs As Worksheet      ' Worksheet Object to be Used in a For Each Loop
  Dim vntSkip As Variant      ' List of Exceptions Array
  Dim vntFormulas As Variant  ' Formulas Array
  Dim lngRows As Long         ' Formulas Array Rows Counter
  Dim intColumns As Integer   ' Formulas Array Columns Counter
  Dim vntWb As Variant        ' Workbooks Array
  Dim intWb As Integer        ' Workbooks Array Rows Counter
  Dim strDel As String        ' Worksheet Reference String ("!" & Sheet1.Name)
  Dim strWb As String         ' Workbooks Array Split String ("]" & strDel)
  Dim strWbTemp As String     ' Workbooks Array Temporary String ("" or strWb)
  Dim strWbResult As String   ' Workbooks Array Resulting String

  With Sheet1
    ' Paste Initial-Range formulas into (1-based 2-dimensional) Formulas Array.
    vntFormulas = .Range(cStrRange).Formula
    ' Define Worksheet Decalaration String
    strDel = .Name & "!"
  End With

  ' Define Workbooks Array Split String to use to not remove worksheet
  ' references to sheets with the same name as Sheet1 in other workbooks.
  strWb = "]" & strDel

  ' Remove worksheet(!) references from formulas in Formulas Array.

  ' In the following For-Next loop, in the comments, "Template" for Sheet1's
  ' name is used.

  For intColumns = LBound(vntFormulas, 2) To UBound(vntFormulas, 2)
    For lngRows = LBound(vntFormulas) To UBound(vntFormulas)

      ' Check if element does not contain "]Template!" which would indicate that
      ' it is linking to a sheet with the same name in another workbook.
      If InStr(1, vntFormulas(lngRows, intColumns), strWb, _
          vbTextCompare) = 0 Then   ' Does NOT contain "]Template!" (strWb).

        ' Check if element contains just "Template!" (strDel).
        If InStr(1, vntFormulas(lngRows, intColumns), strDel, _
            vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then    ' DOES contain "Template!" (strDel).
          ' Write resulting string to Formulas Array (overwriting).
          vntFormulas(lngRows, intColumns) = Replace(vntFormulas(lngRows, _
              intColumns), strDel, "", , , vbTextCompare)
'         Else                          ' Does NOT contain "Template!" (strDel).
        End If

       Else                         ' DOES contain "]Template!" (strWb).

        strWbResult = ""
        ' Split the element's string by "]Template!" (strWb) into a 0-based
        ' 1-dimensional array.
        vntWb = Split(vntFormulas(lngRows, intColumns), strWb, , vbTextCompare)
        ' Rebuild the string removing additional "Template!" (strDel) strings.
        For intWb = LBound(vntWb) To UBound(vntWb)
          If intWb <> 0 Then ' Is NOT first element of array.
            strWbTemp = strWb
           Else              ' IS first element of array.
            strWbTemp = ""
          End If
          ' Check if element contains just "Template!" (strDel).
          If InStr(1, vntWb(intWb), strDel, _
              vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then  ' DOES contain "Template!" (strDel).
            strWbResult = strWbResult & strWbTemp & Replace(vntWb(intWb), _
                strDel, "", , , vbTextCompare)
           Else                         ' Does NOT contain "Template!" (strDel).
            strWbResult = strWbResult & strWbTemp & vntWb(intWb)
          End If
        Next
        Erase vntWb
        ' Write resulting string to Formulas Array (overwriting).
        vntFormulas(lngRows, intColumns) = strWbResult

      End If

    Next
  Next

  With Sheet1
    ' Populate (0-based 1 dimensional) List of Exceptions Array (vntSkip),
    ' after adding Sheet1's name (.Name i.e. Sheet1.Name).
    vntSkip = Split(cStrSkip & cStrSkipSeparator & .Name, cStrSkipSeparator)
    ' Paste Formulas Array (vntFormulas) into the range (same size and position
    ' as the Initial Range (cStrRange)) of each worksheet whose name is not
    ' contained in the List of Exceptions (vntSkip) in the workbook
    ' (.Parent.Name i.e. Sheet1.Parent.Name) where Sheet1 resides.
    For Each objWs In Workbooks(.Parent.Name).Worksheets
      If IsError(Application.Match(objWs.Name, vntSkip, 0)) Then _
          objWs.Range(cStrRange).Formula = vntFormulas
    Next
  End With

  Erase vntSkip
  Erase vntFormulas

End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```